# asp.net mvc3 with a extern sql server, how?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-express

i'm currently trying to make a asp.net mvc3 app. in the sample application which is generatet when i create the project, there is a user management.

the problem is, now the app created a database in my App_Data folder, but i want to have it on my external sqlexpress server.

but i dont know how to change the app so that it works. i just have the following things from my server:

- hostname
- database name
- username
- password

i know that i have to edit the connection string in the Web.config, but must i also change some things at the sql server?

because there are no tables, its empty. does the mvc3 create all automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run **aspnet_regsql.exe** utility from C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 folder on your machine.

http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2009/10/02/installing-asp-net-membership-services-database-in-sql-server-expreess.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Before you start using the Development edition, you need to be aware what it is and what the limitations are of you using it.

SQLExpress is perfectly fine for using, both for dev and when you release your product. It has the same engine as SQL Standard, but with a couple restrictions in place, such as a max file size of 4GB (and i think it also has a RAM limit, but not sure on that one). You are allowed to use SQL Express as the backend for your website with no extra licencing costs (i.e. - free). I have worked at one place where they worked out a system of chaining several instances of SQL Express together just to get round the 4GB file limit - but be aware that this may contravene the licence of it.

SQL Developer is actually SQL Enterprise, but without the install time restriction on OS. You are also not permitted to use SQL Developer in production (i.e. for your live app). For most purposes whatever you code on SQL Developer can also execute on SQL express, but you have to be careful not to use any of the Enterprise features - licencing Enterprise can be a pricey option.

So go ahead and use SQL Express, it is a good option.

P.S. - i am assuming that your database won't be high load - if it is then you would need to consider either Standard or Enterprise.

-Slugster

[Is SQL Server Express a serviceable database for a ASP.NET MVC web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084580/is-sql-server-express-a-serviceable-database-for-a-asp-net-mvc-web-application)

In terms of how to implement see here
[How to Connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 Using EF and MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246167/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-2008-r2-using-ef-and-mvc-3)